# Railo not trapping IIS errors

Tags: tomcat, error-handling, iis-7.5, railo

I have the standard Railo installation, Railo 4, Tomcat.

I have recently moved from Coldfusion to Raiolo but non of the errors are being caught. Instead i get the ASP / IIS error messages which are no good as our custom website error pages do not get displayed.

Can anyone help with this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-state what you're asking, you want to display the Railo error message instead of the IIS error message.

What is probably happening is an error code is being sent back from Railo which IIS is then intercepting. For security reasons, IIS by default displays a very non-descript error instead of the more detailed error from the application itself. IIS is trying to protect you from giving away too much information to bad guys who may be trying to do bad things to your site.

To fix this in IIS7, you can change how IIS handles errors from your application.

- Open IIS
- Click on your site
- Click on the "Error Pages" icon under the "IIS" heading
- Click "Edit Feature Settings" in the right side menu
- Select the "Detailed Errors" radio button
- Click "OK"

Now re-test your site and see if your error message from Railo is displayed.

Hope this helps!